# Extract row data from dictionary if dataframes based on filter on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, concatenation

The dictionary dict_set has dataframes as the value for their keys.

I'm trying to extract data from a dictionary of dataframes based on a filter on 'A' column in the dataframe based on the value in column.

```
dict_set={}
dict_set['a']=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,2,3]})
dict_set['b']=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,5],'B':[1,5,6]})
    
df=pd.concat([dict_set[x][dict_set[x]['A']==1] for x in dict_set.keys()],axis=0)
```

output being the below.

```
   A  B
0  1  1
0  1  1
```

But I would want the output to be

```
   A  B  x
0  1  1  a
0  1  1  b
```

Basically, I want the value of x to be present in the new dataframe formed as a column, say column x in the dataframe formed such that df[x] would give me the x values. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Add `dict_set` to the question, and what's some error? Post the whole error traceback.

Comment: @Ch3steR done. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pd.concat([df.query("A == 1") for df in dict_set.values()], keys=dict_set.keys())\
  .reset_index(level=0)\
  .rename(columns={'level_0':'x'})
```

Output:

```
   x  A  B
0  a  1  1
0  b  1  1
```

***Details:***

Let's get the dataframes from the dictionary using list comprehension and filter the datafames. Here, I choose to use `query`, but you could use boolean index with `df[df['A'] == 1]` also, then `pd.concat` with the `keys` parameter set to the dictionary keys.  Lastly, `reset_index` level=0 and `rename`.